# Problemas con Maven2 en testeo de proyecto dentro IDE Eclipse Marte 2

Tags: gvnix, maven

Quisiera comentaros algo que me sucede cuando hago un testeo de un proyecto que he creado IDE Eclipse:

Dentro del IDE Eclipse, en la parte de Roll Shell, introduzco el siguiente comando:

`perform test`

– Me aparece este error:

```
ests run: 45, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ————————————————————————
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ————————————————————————
[INFO] Total time: 10.909 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-14T17:56:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/200M
[INFO] ————————————————————————
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project CustomerdbRoo: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Raulv\Documents\EclipseSpringRoo\CustomerdbRoo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
~.domain.CbEnterprise roo-gvNIX>
```

Tengo creadas las rutas del `MAVE_HOME` y de `JAVA_HOME` correctamente pero por mucho que reviso, no puedo ejecutar este comando, ni encontrar el problema.

Comment: @aldanux gracias por la corrección , tengo que aprender correctamente a editar los mensajes.